# How to show a lable at specific co-ordinate in PySide6

Tags: python, qlabel, pyside6

Suppose I have this label

```py
text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
```

Now I want to show this label at a co-ordinate of 100, 90 meaning I want its top-left most pixel at that co-ordinate. How can I do that?

I already tried using indent but it seems that it pushes the object 100 pixels in both x and y direction

```py
text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World", indent = 100)
```

Is there something like

```py
text.exec(QtCore.QPoint(100, 90))
```

Extra information: this example was given PySide docs

```py
import sys
import random
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "Hei maailma", "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("File")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante i gave all the infomation is the title not enough to convey it? I don't know what extra to add. I just want to show the label at specific coordinate rather than showing it by alignment or indent. Did my question didnt explain that?

Comment: It's not sufficient, sorry. For instance, is the label added to the "parent" widget/window? Is it part of a layout? Or is it a standalone widget (aka, top level window)? Is the requested coordinate based on the parent, or the absolute position relative to the window, or based on the layout item used for it? If it's part of the layout, should the label consider that "margin" when resizing the parent, to ensure that it doesn't get partially hidden when the parent is resized? As you can see, there are many aspects that your question didn't consider, that's why we ask you to add more details.

Comment: @musicamante i edited it with the information you wanted

Comment: so should the label be shown below the button or should everything be shifted along with the label, thus leaving an empty space above? Please try to be as clear as you can about the wanted result, as there are many ways of interpreting your current request and, therefore, many ways to implement them. It would also help a lot if you could provide an image mockup of the desired result, and also know what should happen if the window is resized/maximized.

Comment: @musicamante alright just show me a example of where the label is at x=100 and y = 100 and the button needs to be at x=100 y= 200 and if i miss some information just take defaults and show a example.

Comment: I cannot directly test right now, but try adding the following after creating the label: `self.text.setStyleSheet('padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 90px;')`

Comment: @musicamante that seems to work but as you were saying that there are many other ways in which it can be done is there any other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, it can be enough to set the padding of the stylesheet:

```
self.text.setStyleSheet('padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 90px;')
```

Alternatively, using the contents margin might work, but it's not guaranteed for all widgets and all OS and styles:

```
self.text.setContentsMargins(100, 90, 0, 0)
```

In that case, it's possible to add the widget into a layout and add that layout to the main one instead:

```
textLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
textLayout.setContentsMargins(100, 90, 0, 0)
textLayout.addWidget(self.text)
self.layout.addLayout(textLayout)
```

Be aware that all this won't ensure that the widget will always stay at that position in case the parent size is increased. A possible solution could be to set the maximum size based on the hint:

```
# after setting the margins
self.text.setMaximumSize(self.text.sizeHint)
```

Note that this **must** be called *every time* the text of the label is changed.